# Visual Studio incorrectly packs wwwroot in NuGet package

Tags: c#, nuget, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I'm currently upgrading from the `*.xproj` with `project.json` format to the `*.csproj` file formats, leveraging the newer Visual Studio 2017 tooling. Below is the version I'm on for both the IDE and the SDK / .NET Core CLI:

#### Visual Studio Version

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 
Version 15.4.3
VisualStudio.15.Release/15.4.3+27004.2008
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.7.02558
```

#### SDK / .NET Core CLI

```
.NET Command Line Tools (2.0.2)

Product Information:
 Version:            2.0.2
 Commit SHA-1 hash:  a04b4bf512

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  6.3.9600
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win81-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.2\

Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host

  Version  : 2.0.0
  Build    : e8b8861ac7faf042c87a5c2f9f2d04c98b69f28d
```

With that said, I'm curious how can I exclude `wwwroot` from my NuGet package that is created without relying on a `.nuspec`. Is this possible?

#### `.csproj`

Here is my `.csproj`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>        
    <!-- omitted for brevity -->
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="wwwroot\**\*;node_modules" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Views\**" Exclude="bin\**;obj\**;**\*.xproj;packages\**;@(EmbeddedResource)" />
    <None Update="NLog.config">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <PackagePath>lib/net461/</PackagePath>
      <Pack>true</Pack>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="wwwroot\**\*">
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- package references, omitted for brevity -->
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

#### Package Content

Here is an image of the package contents:

[image]

Ideally, I want to content to resemble exclude the `content` and `contentFiles` bits and instead just be the `lib` with the `.exe`.

Comment: Do you really want to pack the executable? are you trying to make a library? Projects using the web sdk aren't package by default because there isn't really a good reusability story for web projects. If you want to make a library, remove the `.Web` from the Sdk - this also removes the content items (if you really want to pack the executable, you can still use msbuild item updates to exclude them from packing)

Comment: Yes, I want to package the `.exe` and I want to exclude the `wwwroot`. We currently have a host executable that consumes other `exe`, loads them into the hosts app domain and exposes their Web API end points - so that we can share hosting dynamically. What disadvantages are there to changing the SDK bit?

Comment: As expose you mean forward requests or load controllers? Then it would be more like a library.. Without web sdk you'll loose vs launch settings, web publishing methods and these modified project item defaults (content/none/wwwroot)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can modify the content items in the project file to set the `Pack` metadata to `false` for either just the wwwroot folder or for all content items:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <!-- only exclude wwwroot items from package -->
  <Content Update="wwwroot/**" Pack="false" />

  <!-- Exclude all content from package (e.g. appsettings.json) -->
  <Content Update="@(Content)" Pack="false" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Perfect, this is what I am looking for and it worked like a charm. Thanks again!!

Comment: How do you do it the other way around and get `dotnet pack` to INCLUDE all files? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69314554/nuget-package-generated-with-dotnet-pack-is-missing-its-own-files