# Nuget package generated with `dotnet pack` is missing its own files

Tags: nuget, csproj, dotnet-cli

N.B. This question is about packaging the project's own files, as opposed to external depencencies. I am not a developer and my guess is that this is so obvious to a developer, it's not documented.

I have a [basic web app](https://github.com/OctopusSamples/RandomQuotes/tree/master/RandomQuotes) that is being used to demonstrate a pipeline. The only change I have made is to add `<IsPackable>true</IsPackable>` to the .csproj file.

Using `dotnet pack` creates a `nupkg` file, but it is missing the main website files such as `wwwroot` and the files therein.

I'm used to using `octo pack` which references the "debug" build/publish folder as opposed to `dotnet pack` that uses the `.csproj` file, therefore I believe my `.csproj` file is missing something, however, my Googling always yields results about referencing 3rd-party Nuget packages. In this instance, I am not trying to reference external packages, I want it to pack its own files.

#### Contents of .nupkg file:

| `octo pack` | `dotnet pack` |
| --- | --- |
| [image: octo pack content] | [image: dotnet pack content] |

### Steps to reproduce (assuming you have the required .Net SDK installed).

1. Download [basic web app](https://github.com/OctopusSamples/RandomQuotes/tree/master/RandomQuotes) and extract to `C:\Temp\RandomQuotes-master`.
2. Edit `C:\Temp\RandomQuotes-master\RandomQuotes\RandomQuotes.csproj`

   1. Add a new element under `<PropertyGroup>`: `<IsPackable>true</IsPackable>`
      [image]
3. `cd` to `C:\Temp\RandomQuotes-master\RandomQuotes`
4. Run `dotnet build`.
5. Run `dotnet run` if you want to check the app works.
6. Package the app. Run `dotnet pack`.

   Result:

   ```
   PS C:\Temp\RandomQuotes-master\RandomQuotes> dotnet pack
   Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.11.0+0538acc04 for .NET
   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

     Determining projects to restore...
     All projects are up-to-date for restore.
     RandomQuotes -> C:\Temp\RandomQuotes-master\RandomQuotes\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\RandomQuotes.dll
     RandomQuotes -> C:\Temp\RandomQuotes-master\RandomQuotes\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\RandomQuotes.Views.dll
     Successfully created package 'C:\Temp\RandomQuotes-master\RandomQuotes\bin\Debug\RandomQuotes.1.0.0.nupkg'.
   ```
7. View the generated `.nupkg` file:

   [image]

If anyone can help, I'd be grateful if you could share your ideas.

T.I.A.

Comment: Did you follow the octo pack instructions from https://octopus.com/docs/packaging-applications/create-packages/octopus-cli, or https://octopus.com/docs/deployments/dotnet/netcore-webapp? `dotnet pack` is only recommended for class libraries, not web applications

Comment: @MartinUllrich, thanks, but this client doesn't have Octopus - hence my headache with dotnet. `dotnet octo pack` doesn't work on a standard .Net SDK install, so I guess it needs Octopus Tools installed. How can I pack a web application into a NuGet package with native Dotnet tooling? Should/am I able to use Octopus Tools without a license, or am I missing what you're saying?

Comment: Then my question is why you would want to do that? you'd need to pack the publish output, a web application isn't meant to be packed as NuGet (in constrast to say a razor class library) by the .net tooling - octo was just using NuGet as a distribution mechanism so they needed their own guidance / tooling for that.

Comment: Thanks @MartinUllrich, maybe I'm not getting it. We "pack" our products and push them to a repository (VSTS Artefacts, Artifactory, Nexus etc). E.g. `myproduct.1.1.0-beta.nupkg`. Packages are then "catalogued" / immutable and we can return to a given version if need be. As you say, I think we are using it as a distribution mechanism. Is NuGet not a suitable archive type to use? How should it be done?